# Download only first few blocks of blockchain

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

Is there an archive location or a place where I could be able to download only the first few hundred blocks of the block chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Qt client on your computer you already have them at [this physical location](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory#blocks_subdirectory)

If you want to retrieve them through Qt's RPC facility then for index `i` = 0 to `i` = 99 iterate: `getblock(getblockhash[i])`